# Rust ndarray mismatched types

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I'm trying to get an Array3 from an image using ndarray_image:

```
pub fn from_png(path: &str) -> Result<Self, &str> {
        return match ndarray_image::open_image(path, Colors::Rgba) {
            Ok(data) => { ;
                let size = Size {
                        x: data.shape()[0],
                        y: data.shape()[1]
                    };
                Ok( Self { data, size } )
            }
            Err(_) => {
                Err("Unable to open image!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Self.data type is Array3 and open_image returns an Array3. It is so strange, but in error types also same:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   |
   |                 Ok( Self { data, size } )
   |                            ^^^^ expected struct `ArrayBase`, found struct `ndarray::ArrayBase`
   |
   = note: expected struct `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<u8>, Dim<[usize; 3]>>`
              found struct `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<u8>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 3]>>`
   = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `ndarray` are being used?
```

About versions: I use version "0" for all ndarray-* crates.

Dependencies in Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
bytes = "1.1.0"
font-kit = "0.10.1"
pathfinder_geometry = "0.5.1"
image = "0.23.14"
rayon = "1.5.1"
ndarray = { version="0", features=["rayon", "serde"]}
serde = "1.0.133"
serde_json = "1.0.74"
ndarray-stats = "0"
ndarray-image = "0"
```

Comment: Could you share the `Cargo.toml` of the crate in question? We can't be sure what dependencies exactly are you using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I get grepping for `ndarray` in whole your dependency tree:

```
$ cargo tree | grep ndarray
├── ndarray v0.15.4
├── ndarray-image v0.3.0
│   └── ndarray v0.14.0
├── ndarray-stats v0.5.0
│   ├── ndarray v0.15.4 (*)
```

As you can see, there are indeed two incompatible versions of `ndarray` - one pulled in by `ndarray-image` and another by `ndarray-stats`.

The reason for this is the fact that Cargo doesn't try to resolve immediate dependencies version based on *their* dependencies. All it does know is that you've requested some `0.x.y` version for each `ndarray-*`, so it picks the latest one - and they happen to be unusable together.

---

To make this work, you have to downgrade your `ndarray` to the lowest version available for other dependencies, i.e. `0.14`.

For direct dependency, this is as easy as just requiring the desired version explicitly.
For `ndarray-stats`, we have to look through the previous versions looking for their dependencies; happily, this is explicitly documented on the [crate page](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray_stats): the version we're looking for is [`0.4.0`](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray_stats/0.4.0/dependencies).
It's also advisable to pin the minor version for `ndarray-image` too, so that the breakage won't appear again unexpectedly on its update.

Now, the corresponding part of `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
ndarray = { version="0.14", features=["rayon", "serde"]}
ndarray-stats = "0.4"
ndarray-image = "0.3"
```

And the output of `cargo tree` is like this:

```
$ cargo tree | grep ndarray
├── ndarray v0.14.0
├── ndarray-image v0.3.0
│   └── ndarray v0.14.0 (*)
├── ndarray-stats v0.4.0
│   ├── ndarray v0.14.0 (*)
```

I can't check your code as-is, since it's not a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but after these changes it should compile - save for possibly now-missing APIs, if you've used something from `ndarray v0.15`.